# Does wp_localize_script call a Javascript Function or Simply Pass PHP Parameters to It

Tags: javascript, ajax, wp-localize-script

Easy question: I'm trying to understand `wp_localize_script`.

Does `wp_localize_script` call a JavaScript function or does it simply pass PHP parameters to JavaScript?

I want to pass PHP parameters to a JavaScript function and call the JS function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wp_localize_script` takes an array of data (in PHP) spits out a javascript.  It's a way for you to add dynamic data for a specific script to the front end without having to hook into wp_head or wp_footer and echo it out yourself.  More over, `wp_localize_script` outputs your data right above the script you enqueued.  Hooking into `wp_head` or `wp_footer` won't do that.

`wp_localize_script` does not call javascript functions.  It's a way to do exactly what you want: pass dynamic data from the server side (PHP) to the client side (javascript).

**An Example**

Your theme needs to take a piece of post meta data and make it accessible to a javascript function.

So you'd hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` and do the following...

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse34008_enqueue' );
function wpse34008_enqueue()
{
    // if we're not on a singular page, bail
    if( ! is_singular() ) return;

    global $post;
    if( empty( $post ) ) $post = get_queried_object();

    // enqueue your script...
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse34008-script', 'http://example.com/path/to/script.js' );

    wp_localize_script(
        'wpse34008-script',
        'wpse34008',
        array(
            'meta' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpse34008_meta', true )
        )
    );
}
```

Then somewhere the enqueued `script.js` file, you can get the post meta like this...

```
// somewhere in the js file
someFunction( wpse34008.meta );
```

Make sense?

Comment: Great explanation! I understand it now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Well explained. +1